# Blender VSE track/clip increase waveform height

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to create an animation based on audio, so seeing the waveform is helpful.

How can I increase the vertical size of an audio clip in the timeline without increasing the size of the timeline itself?

I get this:

[image: too small clip height]

I want this (without having to fullscreen the VSE):

[image: just right clip height]

Comment: Also you can place markers on the beat without needing to see the waveform. Just set the sync mode to AV (in the timeline window), this will force Blender to play the sound back at full frame rate. As you play tap the M key to add markers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key and middle mouse button and move the mouse up to zoom in.

[image]

Comment: Much better than the method of dragging something in the left scroll bar (I'm still not sure which element in that bar exactly needs to be dragged. So flaky.) Thanks!

Comment: Amazing it still works in 2.92 ;-) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Click and drag the left side bar to change vertical size / height of clips/strips/tracks.

[image: click here]

Then middle-mouse-button-drag to reposition your view.

Answer (score 2):

The Vertical Scrollbar where you can zoom in/out of clips/strips/tracks has moved to the right hand side of timeline by Blender 2.90